# Unable to adjust screen brightness on dual-booted Macbook Pro (Mid-2010 13'')

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, brightness, macbook, backlight

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my old Macbook Pro (mid-2010, 13'', Intel Core Duo) running a dual-boot with macOS as per [these instructions](https://linuxnewbieguide.org/how-to-install-linux-on-a-macintosh-computer/). Everything appears to be running smoothly, but I cannot adjust the backlight brightness nor connect and external monitor (both working fine on the macOS partition). Having browsed various forums like this one, I've found that my `/sys/class/backlight/` folder is empty, which apparently may indicate that hardware is not recognized. Some suggested editing the `/etc/default/grub/`, in particular to change the corresponding line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` but this has not changed anything. Similarly I tried using `xbacklight` following other suggestions, but also no luck.

I'm using NVIDIA as an additional driver (limited understanding of what it actually does) and my graphics card appears to be `04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 [GeForce 320M] (rev a2)` (from `$ lspci`).

Very new to all of this so please let me know if you need any more information. Grateful for any advice!

Thanks